# Using PL/SQL Cursor to return a result set for reporting tool

Tags: oracle, plsql, reporting, toad, toad-data-point

I'm a report writer.  My queries are generally SELECT statements from some source (in this case Oracle Exadata) that Selects from one or more tables, joins, filters in WHERE, further filters groups in HAVING, etc.  I generally have READ only rights to whatever source I'm connecting to.  So, I can't create sprocs, packages, or functions.

I have a need to use advanced functionality on a complex query, using FOR..LOOPs, IF THEN ELSE structures, etc. to refine a derived result-set for output to a reporting tool such as Qlikview or Tableau.

As I'm learning as I go, I've found many lessons on using cursors in complex logic structures but every lesson uses dbms_output.put_line as the result of each iteration.  The output ends up in the buffer, instead of the Result Set.  I've learned that a SYS_REFCURSOR is a pointer to a result set.  Sound promising but all the examples start with CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE/PACKAGE.

There are gaps in my understanding I'm hoping you can fill if I explain what my desired outcome is:

I have a complex query that synthesizes multiple SELECT statements by UNION'ing them, uses sub-selects in Join and Where clauses, etc.  It returns a nearly complete Result Set but I have need to further refine it before sending the Result Set to the reporting tool.

I can:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR current_Schedule IS
  SELECT --insert complex query here-- ;

  row_Schedule  cur_Schedule%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  IF NOT current_Schedule%ISOPEN THEN
    OPEN current_Schedule;
  END IF;

  LOOP
    FETCH current_Schedule INTO row_Schedule;
    EXIT WHEN current_Schedule%NOTFOUND;
    --Here's where I think my question is....
    dbms_output.put_line('row_Schedule.Login ' || row_Schedule.Code)
  END LOOP;

EXCEPTION --put exception clause here

END;
```

This works and validates the concept that I can iterate through the results of the complex query, update, filter, etc. but the problem is....

It outputs to the Buffer, not the Result Set.

It's likely I'm mis-understanding some PL/SQL concepts.  All of the research examples I've found here and other sources assume the user has the ability to create Functions, Packages, etc.

I'm limited to launching this as a script from a QlikView ODBC connection with Read Only rights to the source.

Is there a solution given my limitations?

Thank you for taking the time to read this and much gratitude if you can provide a coherent answer.

mfc

---

EDIT: Additional Information

I'm working with a Work Force Management Schema, de-normalized and housed in an Exadata data-lake.  I have 2 tables DET_SEG (Detailed Segment) and GEN_SEG (General Segment).  DET_SEG contains fk's to Employee and Segment Code tables, NOM_DATE, START MOMENT and STOP MOMENT.  Codes are of 2 types, Additive and Subtractive. Additive are Work Codes indicating business units employees are assigned to, Subtractive codes are any type of code that takes an employee from work such as Break, Lunch, Sick, etc.  All codes are tied to a table that generates Time Intervals at 30 minutes.  As code could occupy a complete or partial interval, and as they can span multiple intervals, I ended up with 6 unique Use Cases to solve for: Code that start before, occupy an entire and end in subsequent Interval is one.  Codes that start before, end within is another.
You can imagine the rest, I won't iterate through them.  The final output generates a computed column titled "Minutes" indicating the amount of time the Additive or Subtractive Code occupied in the Interval.

I ended up creating 6 unique SELECT blocks UNION'ed together to output the penultimate solution.  Here's an example of one of the shorter SELECT's:

```
SELECT 
  cal.GlobalIntervals AS G_Intervals,
  mainstart.startmoment AS StartMoment,
  mainstart.stopmoment AS StopMoment,
  mainstart.code as Code,
  mainstart.ID AS Login,
  ((case mainstart.code
        when 'BRK1' then round(24*60*(mainstart.startmoment -mainstart.stopmoment),0)
        when 'BRK2' then round(24*60*(mainstart.startmoment - mainstart.stopmoment),0)
        when 'BRK3' then round(24*60*(mainstart.startmoment - mainstart.stopmoment),0)
        else round(24*60*(mainstart.startmoment - mainstart.stopmoment),0)
  end)) as Minutes  
from
(
SELECT
    (
    to_date(to_char((
    SELECT CLNDR_DT
    FROM COMMOBJ.DIM_DATE
    where CLNDR_DT = trunc(sysdate)
    ), 'dd-mon-yyyy') || HOUR_24_LABEL_CD, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    ) as GlobalIntervals
FROM    COMMOBJ.DIM_TIME t
WHERE   second_nbr = 0
AND     mod(minute_nbr, 30) = 0 
) cal
left outer join
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
        New_time(to_date(30121899,'ddMMyyyy')+EWFM.DET_SEG.START_MOMENT/1440,'GMT','PST') as StartMoment,
    New_time(to_date(30121899,'ddMMyyyy')+EWFM.DET_SEG.STOP_MOMENT/1440,'GMT','PST') as StopMoment,
    SEG_CODE.CODE,
    SEG_CODE.DESCR,
    EMP.ID,
    EMP.LAST_NAME,
    EMP.FIRST_NAME 
FROM EWFM.DET_SEG DET_SEG
    INNER JOIN EWFM.SEG_CODE SEG_CODE ON (DET_SEG.SEG_CODE_SK = SEG_CODE.SEG_CODE_SK)
    INNER JOIN EWFM.EMP EMP ON (DET_SEG.EMP_SK = EMP.EMP_SK)
    INNER JOIN SBCG_ADHOC.SBCG_STAFF SBCG_STAFF ON (EMP.ID = SBCG_STAFF.AGENT_LOGIN)
    WHERE trunc (New_time(to_date(30121899,'ddMMyyyy')+EWFM.DET_SEG.START_MOMENT/1440,'GMT','PST')) =  trunc(sysdate)  
    and EWFM.SEG_CODE.CRNT_REC_IND = 'Y'
    and SEG_CODE.CODE NOT IN ('SHIFT', 'CCBOUT', 'HOLIDA', 'LIND', 'PCHT', 'PIND', 'PXTR', 'LCHT', 'LXTR', 'PSVC', 'HV Saves Inbound' )
  )mainstart
  --StartMoment occurs AFTER Current Interval
  on  cal.GlobalIntervals < mainstart.StartMoment 
  --StopMoment occurs on Next Interval 
  and (cal.GlobalIntervals + (1/24/60 * 30)) = mainstart.StopMoment 
  --StartMoment occurs prior to Next Interval
  and mainstart.StartMoment < (cal.GlobalIntervals + (1/24/60 * 30))
```

The output looks like this:

G_INTERVALS   | STARTMOMENT   | STOPMOMENT    | CODE | LOGIN  | MINUTES
4/17/17 12:00  | 2/17/17 12:00  | 2/17/17 12:15  | BRK1  | ABC123  | -15
4/17/17 12:00  | 2/17/17 12:00  | 2/17/17 08:00  | SHIFT | XYZ321  |  30
4/17/17 12:30  | 2/17/17 12:45  | 2/17/17 01:45  | LUNCH | LK4567  | -15

The Case statement for the Minutes column changes for each Use Case as does the ON condition in the final Join.  Although perhaps not the most efficient, it generates a dataset that is almost ready for a **Shrinkage Report**.

The final condition (and the reason for this post) is the GEN_SEG table.  It contains information for Day Long events such as Planned Sick (SICKPL), unplanned Sick (SICKUP), etc.  It only has a date, no START or STOP moments.  This is where I was looking for further refinement.  Either using a Cursor to iterate through the Result-Set and for every Login found in the GEN_SEG, and For every value <0, change it to 0 in order to zero out the negative values associated with the Subtractive Codes.

Ultimately we want to discover Shrinkage within a workforce.  The employee schedule is only the first step.  Once the Employee Schedule with planned and unplanned shrinkage has been refined, I'll bring in the Actuals for further refinement.

I suspect I've written a short novel  but I hope I've included just enough detail to explain the need for a secondary tier of refinement.  If you have any ideas or critique, I'm grateful.

Cheers~!

Comment: Hi, why you are looking for **Result set**? have you tried views?

Comment: @hmmftg - the OP states " I can't create sprocs, packages, or functions" which rules out views too.

Comment: If your organisation won't allow you to create (or get created) objects to support reporting you're pretty limited in your options. You will have to focus on solving this *" It returns a nearly complete Result Set but I have need to further refine it before sending the Result Set to the reporting tool"* **in SQL**. You'd be surprised what is possible in Oracle SQL these days. Obviously we can't help you solve that problem unless you tell us the details of this post processing. Also, tell us which version of Oracle you're using.

Comment: Thank you APC, I've added more detail to my original question.  I hope I've described my problem well enough to explain my need for post-processing.  It should be noted that everything I proto-type for this script is done in Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

In your PL/SQL block you are consuming the cursor, so there is nothing to return to the client.

You could return a cursor from an anonymous block if you are on Oracle 12c (see [implicit result sets](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1)), but then you are back to SQL with no procedural control.

Probably what you'd want is a [pipelined function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions) which gives you in effect a procedural view. However, you can't do this from a read-only account as you would need to create the function and the collection type it returns.

You can do a lot with SQL though. I'd be interested to know what reporting requirement needs procedural logic.

Comment: William, Thank you for your response.  I'm going to answer both here and in my original question (due to the char limitations on comments).  I'm still new to PL/SQL and trying to wean my way from thinking in terms of T-SQL.  Oracle SQL seems more powerful but the learning curve is a bit steeper, the syntax more complex and there are concepts that don't seem to translate well between the two.  Please see my edit above.  Thank you